# Activating div while hovering over underlaying div - CSS transition not working

Tags: css, hover, transition

First of all, I'm sorry if this question was already answered but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I'm trying to get a smooth transition when hovering over a div. On top of this div is another div, which gets visible when hovering. The transition didn't seem to do the trick, so how can I pull this off? (jquery instead of CSS, or other/better code?)

Maybe there's another way of doing this, I hope you guys can help me.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="hover">
        <a href="#">
            <p>Test</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <img src="#" alt="img" />
    <div class="text">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body     {    background-color: #eee;
}

ul  {       margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;}

ul li     { width: 30.33%;
            height: auto;
            margin-right: 3%;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: #fff;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}

ul li img     { width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                z-index: 1;
                background-color: #ddd;
                border: 0;}

.text       {   width: 100%;
                padding-top: 7%;}

.text p     {   margin: 0 10px;
                padding-bottom: 7%;}

.hover  {   height: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: none;}

.hover a    {   width:100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 25px;
                display: block;
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}

ul li:hover > .hover     {  display: block;
                            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
                            -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
                            transition: all 0.2s ease;}
```

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/HAFEx/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should the transition look like? Are you expecting the element to fade in?

Comment: You cannot transition the `display` property.

Comment: Most likely you'll want to change `display: none` to `opacity: 0`, and `display: block` to `opacity: 1`, and do cross browser (older IE) equivalents.

Comment: Piggybacking off of what Paulie_D said, what you can try is changing the opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display:block can't be afected by a transition.
Instead use opacity.

```
.hover  {   height: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
            opacity:0;
}


ul li:hover > .hover{
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rjq3y/

Comment: Please try not to post the same answer as previous ones :) We try to stay away from duplicates

Comment: When I posted this comment the others were not updated on my borwser, sorry... #norage

Answer (score 1):

A couple things need to be changed. Firstly, you can't animate the `display` property, so you should toggle opacity on hover instead.

Secondly, you should apply the transition on `.hover`, not just on `parent:hover .hover` so that it transitions both ways.

Using both of those improvements (and some formatting of your code) you get [**this result**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/HAFEx/1/)

```
.hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    opacity:0;
    ... Other properties ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transition css `display`. Try opacity.
http://jsfiddle.net/HAFEx/2/

```
ul li:hover .hover {    
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also jquery to animate the display:none property.

```
$("li").mouseover(function(){
 $(".hover").fadeIn(1000);
});

$(".hover").mouseout(function(){
 $(".hover").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Check out this codepen.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqozA

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question asked

Answer (score 0):

The `display` property is a number or hexadecimal value, so it cannot be tweened. In this circumstance, you can't simply have the hover state opacity: 0.

Two work arounds are Javascript (messy) and using CSS Keyframe animations. http://hschwarz77.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/css-transition-from-display-none-to-display-block-on-hover/

To the best of my knowledge, these are the only solutions to have the div completely hidden (and unusable...visibility:hidden occupies the space) and fade in.

Comment: I believe you forgot the word "not" in your first sentence

Comment: He did ask for a solution through jquery.